# Can't move a std::unique_lock into a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, move-semantics

I'm trying to create a very simple, bare-bones C++ class to implement a thread-safe list, i.e. one which is automatically locked when you access it. Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't want to allow me to create and return a struct that contains a `unique_lock`. This is what I tried at first:

```
template<typename T>
struct LockedQueue {
    private:
        std::mutex mutex;
        using lock_t = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;
        std::list<T> underlying_list;
    public:
        struct LockedListAccess {
            private:
                lock_t lock;
            public:
                std::list<T> &access;
        };
        LockedListAccess locked() {
            return LockedListAccess{ lock_t{mutex}, underlying_list };
        }
};
```

This fails with

```
no matching function for call to ‘LockedQueue<tcp::socket>::LockedListAccess::LockedListAccess(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)
```

I'm guessing this means that brace initializer lists/C++11 unified initialization for structs don't work with move-only types like std::unique_lock. So I tried creating an explicit constructor for my struct that takes the unique_lock as an rvalue reference, and moves it into the member:

```
template<typename T>
struct LockedQueue {
    private:
        std::mutex mutex;
        using lock_t = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;
        std::list<T> underlying_list;
    public:
        struct LockedListAccess {
            private:
                lock_t lock;
            public:
                std::list<T> &access;
                LockedListAccess(lock_t&& l, std::list<T>& a) :
                    lock(l), access(a) {};
        };
        LockedListAccess locked() {
            return LockedListAccess{ std::move(lock_t{mutex}), underlying_list };
        }
};
```

However, this also fails, giving me the error

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_lock<_Mutex>::unique_lock(const std::unique_lock<_Mutex>&) [with _Mutex = std::mutex]’
```

This compiler error is especially confusing, because it points at the line containing `lock(l), access(a)` as the one where I'm trying to use the deleted copy constructor of std::unique_lock. I declared `l` as a `lock_t&&`, so how could I possibly be calling the copy constructor?

Most resources I could find on the internet seem to indicate that you can move unique_locks around with std::move, though no one seems to address the question of how to construct an object that contains a unique_lock by using std::move. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem:**

In the context of the `LockedListAccess` constructor, `lock_t&& l` is actually an l-value. So you need to cast it back to an r-value using `std::move`. General rule of thumb: Always `std::move` r-value references and always `std::forward` forwarding references.

**Solution:**

```
LockedListAccess(lock_t&& l, std::list<T>& a) 
    : lock(std::move(l))
    , access(a) 
{}
```

Also you do not need to move the temporary lock object because the compiler will automatically bind a temp object to an r-value reference.

This:

```
LockedListAccess locked() {
    return LockedListAccess{ std::move(lock_t{mutex}), underlying_list }
}
```

can become this:

```
LockedListAccess locked() {
    return LockedListAccess{ lock_t{mutex}, underlying_list }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a weird language "feature." I would never expect that something declared `lock_t&&` would suddenly become `lock_t&` just because it's in a constructor. And it looks unnecessary to `std::move` something that's already an rvalue. Thanks for teaching me another C++ quirk.

Comment: It does not become `lock_t&`. It is still an r-value reference that is bound to a temp object but it is used as an l-value. This confused me at first but actually makes sense if you know what an l-value is. I.E: anything that is named will most probably be an l-value and your `lock_t&&` has a name which is `l`;